# variable declare depending on getdate

Tags: sql, variables

I'm trying to create a statement with to variables that depend on the getdate.

For example if the `getdate()` is 31-05-2021 then my variable `@peiljaarstart` must be '2021-01-01' if the month of the `getdate() = 1` then the `@peiljaarstart` must be '2020-01-01'. This is working in the statement below.

The problem is that the variable to set `@peiljaarend` must be `month(getdate())` minus 1. With an extra clause that if the `month(getdate()) = 1` then the variable `@peiljaareind` must be in the previous year.

- For example if the date is '2021-01'15',
  then the variables are '2020-01-01 till '2020-12-31'
- if the date is '2021-02-01',
  then the variables art '2021-01-01 till 2021-01-31'

Hope somebody can help me to solve this.

Statement:

```
declare @peiljaar date
declare @peiljaarstart date
declare @peiljaareind varchar(10)

--bepalen begindatum peiljaar op basis van lopende maand is deze 1 dan vorig jaar meten anders huidig jaar
set @peiljaar = case 
                when convert(varchar,(month(getdate()))) <> '1' then convert(varchar,(year(getdate()))) 
                else convert(varchar,(year(getdate())-1)) end

set @peiljaarstart =   left(@peiljaar,4) 


--bepalen einddatum peiljaar lopende maand minus 1 tenzij lopende maand = 1 dan vorig jaar maand 12
set @peiljaareind = convert(varchar, (left(@peiljaar,4)) ) + '-' + SUBSTRING(CONVERT(nvarchar(6),getdate(), 112),5,2) + '-' + SUBSTRING(CONVERT(nvarchar(6),getdate(), 105),1,2)


--show values 


select 
   @peiljaar
,  @peiljaarstart
, @peiljaareind
```

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using, which is presumably SQL Server.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to want variables that are for the first and last day of the current year.  That would be:

```
set @yearstart = datefromparts(year(getdate()), 1, 1);
set @yearend = datefromparts(year(getdate()), 12, 31);
```

Comment: thnx for your answer but that is not exactly what I'm looking for. I need a start variable thats on the first date of the year. when month(getdate()) = 1 then I need the variable starting in the previous year. This part of the statement already works. More difficult is the variable for the enddate. This is always the last date of the previous month. Exception is when month)getdate()) = 1 then it is 31st december of the year(getdate()) -1

Comment: does anyone have a suggestion how to solve my problem as mentioned above?

Answer (score 0):

this solution works it's not ideal but as long the resuls are good who cares.

```sql
--Variabele begin en einddatum bepalen selectie van begin jaar tot laatste datum vorige maand tov huidige maand 


declare @peiljaar date
declare @peiljaarstart date
declare @peiljaareind varchar(10)

--bepalen begindatum peiljaar op basis van lopende maand is deze 1 dan vorig jaar meten anders huidig jaar
set @peiljaar = case 
                when convert(varchar,(month(getdate()))) <> 1 then convert(varchar,(year(getdate()))) 
                else convert(varchar,(year(getdate())-1)) end

set @peiljaarstart =   left(@peiljaar,4) 


--bepalen einddatum peiljaar lopende maand minus 1 tenzij lopende maand = 1 dan vorig jaar maand 12
set @peiljaareind = case
                    when convert(varchar,(month(getdate()))) = 1 then convert(varchar, (left(@peiljaar,4))-1 ) + '-12-31'
                    when convert(varchar,(month(getdate()))) = 2 then convert(varchar, (left(@peiljaar,4)) ) + '-01-31'
                    when convert(varchar,(month(getdate()))) = 3 then convert(varchar, (left(@peiljaar,4)) ) + '-02-28'
                    when convert(varchar,(month(getdate()))) = 4 then convert(varchar, (left(@peiljaar,4)) ) + '-03-31'
                    when convert(varchar,(month(getdate()))) = 5 then convert(varchar, (left(@peiljaar,4)) ) + '-04-30'
                    when convert(varchar,(month(getdate()))) = 6 then convert(varchar, (left(@peiljaar,4)) ) + '-05-31'
                    when convert(varchar,(month(getdate()))) = 7 then convert(varchar, (left(@peiljaar,4)) ) + '-06-30'
                    when convert(varchar,(month(getdate()))) = 8 then convert(varchar, (left(@peiljaar,4)) ) + '-07-31'
                    when convert(varchar,(month(getdate()))) = 9 then convert(varchar, (left(@peiljaar,4)) ) + '-08-31'
                    when convert(varchar,(month(getdate()))) = 10 then convert(varchar, (left(@peiljaar,4)) ) + '-09-30'
                    when convert(varchar,(month(getdate()))) = 11 then convert(varchar, (left(@peiljaar,4)) ) + '-10-31'
                    when convert(varchar,(month(getdate()))) = 12 then convert(varchar, (left(@peiljaar,4)) ) + '-11-30'

                    --when convert(varchar,(month(getdate()))) > 1 then convert(varchar, (left(@peiljaar,4)) ) + '-' + SUBSTRING(CONVERT(nvarchar(6),getdate(), 112),5,2) + '-' + SUBSTRING(CONVERT(nvarchar(6),getdate(), 105),1,2)
                    else convert(varchar, (left(@peiljaar,4)) ) + '-12-31'
                    end


--show values 


select 
   @peiljaar                            as peiljaar
,  @peiljaarstart                       as peiljaarstart
, @peiljaareind                         as peiljaareind
, convert(varchar,(month(getdate())))   as huidigemaand
```